# Divide string into value and unit

Tags: c#

I have a string that contains a number and its value. The value always precedes the unit. How can I divide the string into two strings?

```
string mainStr = "43.21 m/s";
string val;
string unit;
```

The val should contain "43.21" and unit should be "m/s".

Comment: Use the [split function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-split-method-in-c-sharp-with-examples/)

Comment: how do I use split that checks to push the value into one string and unit into another? As the values can be even longer and unit can be different.

Comment: It seems that the value precedes the unit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the divider between the value and the unit will always be a space, then you can use the [split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0) function and save the result into two different strings.

```
string myString = "43.21 m/s";
string[] split = myString.Split(' ');

string val = split[0];
string unit = split[1];
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do the job:

```
    string mainStr = "43.21 m/s";
    var result = mainStr.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); //will remove empty occurencies if you put multiple spaces

    string val = result[0];
    string unit = result[1];
```